# Swift set UIButton setBorderColor in Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to set UIButton Border color on Storyboard:

[image: Set button color]

But the button is still Black. When I try to use layer.borderColor, it doesn't show the border at all.

How to se the color?

Thank you

**// UPDATE**

I've changed the way to set up based on @dfd to:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

public class OnboardingButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable public var borderColor:UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
   }
   @IBInspectable public var borderWidth:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
   }
   @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius:CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
   }
}
```

After set up in Storyboard Custom Class to ***OnboardingButton** app started build but Faield. There is no error in the Log. Where can I find the error and how to fix it?

Comment: This looks like you made an IBDesignable to UIButton. Did you make an IBInspectable? And please, we can easily debug this - but show us your code!

Comment: Better to do with subclass, because UIButton color takes CGColor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my UIButton subclass:

```
@IBDesignable
public class Button: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable public var borderColor:UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable public var borderWidth:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius:CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I created a simple project and added the above IBDesignable subclass. Below are three screen shots of the result. Note that in the Identity inspector I've set the Class to be Button, not UIButton and that it reports that the Designables are "Up to date". Note that in the Attributes inspector these appear as properties at the very top.

[image: Identity inspector]
[image: Attributes inspector]
[image: Storyboard snapshot]

Comment: I'm trying to use it, but I'm stil getting Designables: Build failed, more on the top. Do you have an idea what happend?

Comment: It looks identical, except for the blank line beneath `IBDesignable` - that (I think) wouldn't make any difference. My only questions aren't related to build errors. Instead of the log, did you check the Issue Navigator? It's the fourth button on the left in Xcode.

Comment: Are the warnings related to the subclassed button? If not, the have you tried to change things in IB? I'll edit my answer with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can change some properties of UIButton form interface builder but not color of border. Another way would be subclassing it like in answer suggested by dfd.