# How to set a default title in UIButton subclass that works in Interface Builder (Xcode 9)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, interface-builder, subclass

I have a button that repeats throughout my app, so I created a subclass to avoid having to set all the basic properties every time.

I am able to set the background colour, the text colour, round the corners.

However, things fall apart when I try to set a default title - something other than "Button".
In Interface Builder it ignores the title, but it also then ignores the font colour, which works when I don't set the title.

If I run the app, it all looks fine, but one major point of using Interface Builder is to save the step of constantly running the app to check basic UI layout.

[image: compare Interface Builder with Actual app]

Here is the subclass.
Note that if you comment out the 2 setTitle lines, the button shows the correct text colour (white).

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class ContinueButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var titleColour: UIColor = .white {
        didSet {
            setTitleColor(titleColour, for: .normal)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bgColour: UIColor = UIColor.gray {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = bgColour
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var buttonTitle: String = "Continue" {
        didSet {
            setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setAttributes()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setAttributes()
    }

    public func setAttributes() {
        setTitleColor(titleColour, for: .normal)
        backgroundColor = bgColour
        setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
    }

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        setAttributes()

        layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * bounds.size.height
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

ps, My main objective is to create a reusable custom button that takes care of setting a bunch of defaults. If there's a better way to achieve that, I'd be very happy to hear that - especially if it could be done visually rather than through code.

Thanks for any advice you can give,

-Nico

Comment: First, why are you *renaming* things? Use `backgroundColor`, etc. **Don't reinvent the wheel!** (You've already subclassed `UIButton`.) Second, have you set the IB (or storyboard) button to actually *be* a `ContinueButton`? Finally, if you need an example of what I'm saying, refer to my answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041809/swift-set-uibutton-setbordercolor-in-storyboard/42041867#42041867 Basically, subclass, set IBDesignable/IBInspectable, and the expose - using the already established properties - what you need.

Comment: I'm renaming because (according to the error messages) you cannot override a variable and then set an initial value to it. The example you show accesses the same named variables in Layer, not directly in UIButton.

Comment: And yes, I did set the button class - without it the end result would not look like my sample pictures. To clarify - I'm trying to use the subclass to avoid setting all the attributes in every button created in IB. The example I showed in the picture uses the attributes set by the subclass only - I didn't customize that button in IB.

Answer (score 0):

Just override prepareForInterfaceBuilder() and add setAttributes().

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    setAttributes()
}
```

Comment: How does this help the issue the OP is facing?

Comment: Why downvote! Please refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402908-prepareforinterfacebuilder. "When Interface Builder instantiates a class with the IB_DESIGNABLE attribute, it calls this method to let the resulting object know that it was created at design time."

Comment: This didn't have any effect. It shows up in IB just as before, with the blue "Button" title.

Comment: It's weird. This does work on my Mac(Xcode Version 9.2). Could you try to re-load storyboard or restart Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The `tintColor` property will do the trick.
`button.tintColor = UIColor.red`

but to make sure to override the `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    button.tintColor = UIColor.red
}
```